# Help with limit question

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Hello can someone help me on this one

> Give definition for
>   $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} a(k) = 0$$
>   and use this definition to show
>   $$
> > \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\sin(k)}{\sqrt{k}} = 0
> > $$

So far as I've gotten in my answer :

The definition is for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $M > 0$, s.t $k>M$ implies $a(k) \to 0$.

Right?
I later use this and start with $|a(k) - 0| < \varepsilon$.

Maybe I can do something like $|\frac{\sin(k)}{\sqrt{k}}*\frac{k}{k} - 0| < \varepsilon = |k/\sqrt{k}|<\varepsilon$

(since $\sin(x)/x=1$)

Am I on the right track with this? And I'm not sure how to continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is almost correct. At the end, instead of $a(k)\to0$, you should have written $\bigl\lvert a(k)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Since$$\left\lvert\frac{\sin k}{\sqrt k}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt k},$$then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1{\sqrt N}<\varepsilon$. Then$$k\geqslant N\implies\left\lvert\frac{\sin k}{\sqrt k}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt k}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt N}<\varepsilon$$